# SQL Where clause use if value passed

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have a following condition.

> If a value is passed to the @UserId parameter i need to filter those
>   user records.
>
> If no value passed, then I need to bring all the records.

*Column RecipientId is NOT NULL*.

But below query always returns all records even though I pass value.

```
DECLARE @UserId INT

SET @UserId = 47

SELECT *
FROM Message MR
WHERE MR.CompanyId = 1
    AND (
        MR.RecipientId IS NOT NULL
        OR MR.RecipientId = @UserId
        )
```

Comment: Change `is not null` to `is null`.

Comment: @user1935361 `is null` not showing any records as the records are always pointing some id

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a boolean expression on your variable

```
declare @UserId  int = null

SELECT *
FROM Message MR
WHERE MR.CompanyId = 1 and (MR.RecipientID = @UserId or @UserId IS NULL)
```

Comment: As i given that my column `Column RecipientId is NOT NULL` in question. Show its not showing any records

Comment: It doesn't matter if that column is null or not. If the parameter is NULL the OR condition is met and all MR.RecipientID's are returned. NULL <> NULL anyways so the null-ability of your column is irrelevant with this operator.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use a simpler form since you provide the id

```
DECLARE @UserId INT

SET @UserId = 47

SELECT *
FROM Message MR
WHERE MR.CompanyId = 1
    AND  MR.RecipientId = @UserId
```

IF no id is provided

```
SELECT *
FROM Message MR
WHERE MR.CompanyId = 1
    AND (
        @UserId IS NULL
        OR MR.RecipientId = @UserId  -- OR get this one, redundant
        )
```

Why:

```
SELECT *
FROM Message MR
WHERE MR.CompanyId = 1
    AND (
        MR.RecipientId IS NOT NULL -- get All NOT NULL *(basically all)
        OR MR.RecipientId = @UserId  -- OR get this one, redundant
        )
```

Comment: The other use case, I wont use or pass the Id to my procedure. I need to handle that case

Answer (score 0):

There is one more alternative, might not be efficient, have a look:

```
DECLARE @UserId INT

SET @UserId = 47

SELECT *
FROM Message MR
WHERE MR.CompanyId = 1
    AND MR.RecipientId = (
        CASE 
            WHEN @UserId IS NULL
                THEN MR.RecipientId
            ELSE @UserId
            END
        )
```